# reusing action listener and jframe in main class

Tags: java, jframe

So if someone would take a look at the code below and give me hand I would owe you my life. So here's the issue, obviously I can get this to work if I were to put `playerCreationSelection`in its own class, my questions is getting it to work, inside `class superClass` I cannot for the life of me move things around to make it work. Any help would be great, thanks everyone!

**forgot to actually put what goes wrong! So what will happen is it says `playerCreationSelection` is not a symbol**

```js
public class superClass
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       playerCreationSeletion gui = new playerCreationSeletion();  
   }

   public class playerCreateSelection extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
   {
   
      //create label
      public JLabel playerCreatedLabel;
      public void playerCreationSeletion()
      {
          setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
          WindowDestroyer listener = new WindowDestroyer();
          addWindowListener(listener);
            
          Container contentPane = getContentPane();
          contentPane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            
          contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            
          //create button
          JButton playerCreationButton = new JButton("Create New Player");
          playerCreationButton.addActionListener(this);
          contentPane.add(playerCreationButton);
            
          //create label
          playerCreatedLabel = new JLabel("Welcome New Player!");
          playerCreatedLabel.setVisible(false);
            
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            if(actionCommand.equals("Create New Player"))
            {
                contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                playerCreatedLabel.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: public class playerCreateSelection needs to be public static class playerCreateSelection

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a typo "playerCreationSeletion()".  Also, You need to call an inner class constructor like this and use setVisible and setSize.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       playerCreateSelection gui = new superClass().new playerCreateSelection();  

       gui.setSize(500, 500);
       gui.setVisible(true);
   }
```

Try that.

Comment: May you should try it first ;)